# how many replication should I make while using wingen program to generate data?

Tags: simulation

Iam writting my thesis and using software called Wingen3 and I am facing problem in determing How many replication should I put when using the program to generate Data?
Some says 5, some says 10,000 but is there a rule or a formula to determine how many replication?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can give you more than a hand-waving guess without knowing more about your specific case.  Note: I know absolutely nothing about "Wingen3", but sample size questions are (or at least ought to be) a function of the statistical properties of your estimators, not of the software.

In general you replicate simulations when they are stochastic to estimate the distributional behavior of the output measures.  How many replications depends entirely on what type of measure you're trying to determine and what margin of error you're willing to tolerate in the estimates.  One fairly common technique is to make a small initial run and estimate the sample variability of your performance measure.  Then project how large a sample will get you down to the desired margin of error.  This works fairly well if you're estimating means, medians, or quartiles, but not at all well for estimating quantiles in the tail of your distribution. For instance, if you want to determine the 99.9%-ile, you're seeking extremes that happen one time in a thousand on average and you may need tens or even hundreds of thousands of replications to accurately assess such rare events.